What are some common locations for oil leaks on a Smart 451?
The Car
I have a 2010 Smart ForTwo with just under 100k miles.  It's a Model 451 with a 1.3L engine.
The Problem
The car is losing oil.  There are no spots on the ground when I move the car, but the oil level drops consistently over time (maybe a quart per month/2000 miles or so).  The exhaust doesn't smoke nor does it smell like burning oil.  There is a dirty, wettish spot on the differential housing just in front of the driver-side axle, but...
Troubleshooting
The most recent time I changed the oil I added some oil-based UV Fluorescent Dye.  I've used it in the past to good results, but this time I haven't seen any bright glowing leaks anywhere when I inspect under the car with a UV light.  Notably, the wet spot on the differential does not have any dye, so either it's an old leak which still hasn't dried (seems unlikely) or the dye isn't leaking yet.  I tested the dye before I filled the engine and it definitely glowed properly under a black light.
The Question
Are there any common locations oil tends to leak on these cars? Is there a way oil could be leaking in such a way to pool onto the differential housing?  More importantly, are there any locations which aren't easily seen from beneath (maybe a leak onto another surface, for example)?  Is it possible the engine is burning that much oil without smoking?

You state it is burning about a quart a month, but you didn't include how many miles that is during the given time, which is very much important.

Have you used a UV light on the inside of the tailpipe?

@GdD I have not tried a UV Light in the Tailpipe, but that's an interesting idea!  I didn't figure the burned, atomized UV dye would be visible, but it's worth a look.

Is it possible the engine is burning that much oil without smoking?  Absolutely!  Every car ever made will begin to "consume" oil, without obvious burning, as it ages.
How to fix:

Flush the crankcase with BG EPR. Change the oil immediately.
While replacing the oil, add Engine Restore.
Add ATP Re-Seal to the engine oil as well, 1/2 oz. per quart.

Allow the additives to work for 3,000 miles.  Problem solved! Re-apply the Restore with any oil change if you feel you want a boost, but use the Re-Seal only once.
